# How to include HTML with styling in custom HTML attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to include a sentence with styling (CSS) into custom HTML attributes.

Is it possible to do so ?

```
 <a class="head-1" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="500" class="active"  data-parameter-1=" Warehouses for rent <br> Starting From <span style="&quot; color:red;text-decoration: underline"&quot; > AED 74,000</span>">WAREHOUSES</a>
```

The only question is how do I escape the double quotes after the style tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible. I haven't tried it with double quotes, but I know that you can use `&lsaquo;` and `&rsaquo;` for `<` and `>` in HTML tags. So I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes instead of double quotes, see the example below. The browser renders the tag correctly.

```html
 <a class="head-1" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="500" class="active"  data-parameter-1=" Warehouses for rent <br> Starting From <span style='color:red;text-decoration: underline'> AED 74,000</span>">WAREHOUSES</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Just remove the double quote `"`, since you use `&quot;`

```js
console.log($(".head-1").attr("data-parameter-1"));

$("#result").html($(".head-1").attr("data-parameter-1"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="head-1" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="500" class="active"  data-parameter-1=" Warehouses for rent <br> Starting From <span style=&quot;color:red;text-decoration:underline&quot;> AED 74,000</span>">WAREHOUSES</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```